# PostgreSQL Row-Level Security is NOT Using Table Indexes

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table with a million rows of data.

[image]

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people; -- 1,000,000 rows

I have created the following 2 indexes:

[image]

Without the RLS enabled, I checked the explain plan of the following query and you can see that it is using the index that I have created for the ct_data JSONB column.

[image]

I enabled Row Level Security by issuing the following commands. The table policy is just a simple condition to have select access on the table.

[image]

With the RLS enabled, I rechecked the explain plan of the same query but this time, it did not use the index and it is doing a parallel sequential scan instead on the "people" table.

[image]

Why is RLS not using the indexes? Appreciate if you could provide some guidance to still implement RLS but not sacrifice performance.

At the moment, if I try to do an update on the ct_data column of the "people" table, it is taking so much time to complete the update especially after I add another simple table policy for the UPDATE DML operation like:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can get better answers at dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Also, please don't use photos for code in questions or answers. They can't be copied which limits the ability of people to answer **and** they can't be indexed by search engines.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the operator `->` is not leakproof:

```
SELECT oprcode
FROM pg_operator
WHERE oprname = '->'
  AND oprleft = 'jsonb'::regtype
  AND oprright = 'text'::regtype;

      oprcode       
════════════════════
 jsonb_object_field
(1 row)

SELECT proleakproof
FROM pg_proc
WHERE proname = 'json_object_field';

 proleakproof 
══════════════
 f
(1 row)
```

Functions and operators that are not leakproof are not optimized to be applied before the condition from the RLS policy for security reasons.

The solution is to pull that `id` column out of the `jsonb` and define it a a regular numeric column. The `=` operators for numeric data types are leakproof.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz for your comment and explanation!